# Deleted workflow is still running

Tags: workflow

There are 2 workflows in my site that still run though I deleted both of them using the SP designer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are they running on new items or current items?  It's possible that previous versions of the workflow are running on old items.

Comment: it's runnning on new items

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: The issue is solved! I cleaned up the workflow history and the old workflows are not triggered anymore